# Computationally cheap substitute of VRP by clustering locations based on Distance

Tags: python-3.x, graph, cluster-analysis

I have a list of locations, and a list of vehicle capacities. I want to cluster locations such that number of points in clusters are equal to capacities of vehicles. Also, while forming clusters, I don't want distance between locations in a cluster to be more than a threshold.

For example, the locations I have is :

```
points = array([[33.    , 41.    ],
       [33.9693, 41.3923],
       [33.6074, 41.277 ],
       [34.4823, 41.919 ],
       [34.3702, 41.1424],
       [34.3931, 41.078 ],
       [34.2377, 41.0576],
       [34.2395, 41.0211],
       [34.4443, 41.3499],
       [34.3812, 40.9793]])
```

vehicle capacities are as follows:

```
capacities = [3, 4, 2]
```

Max distance between two consecutive locations in a cluster should be less than say `3 kms`.

i.e. If locations 1->2->3->4 are in a cluster then this distance limit applies to orders 1,2 and 2,3 and 3,4.

Any solution to this problem? I don't want to use `vrpy` or `ortools`.